# How to write different events from different functions in my file to a log file in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to write events like current user's ip, username, login time to a log file. I have built the functions in php using WordPress hooks for the various events but how to bring them all together to my log function i don't know. These are my codes:

global $active_user;

```
      /**
        * function to get loggedin user's username
        */
        add_action('init', 'log_file_setup');
        function log_file_setup(){

        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';

        $file = fopen($path,"w+");
        $person = "John\n";


        file_put_contents($path, $person, FILE_APPEND );
        }

       /**
        * function to get loggedin user's username
        */

        function get_username(){

         if(is_user_logged_in()){
         $active_user = wp-get-current-user(); 
         $username = $active_user->login;

         return  $username;
         }
        }

       /**
        * function to get loggedin user's Role(s)
        */

        function get_userole(){

         if(is_user_logged_in()){
         $active_user = wp-get-current-user(); 

         // I have cast this into an array because the user may have multiple roles
         $userroles = ( array ) $active_user->roles; 
          return $userroles;
         }
        }
```

Comment: You also have a typo in your function's name. Instead of `wp-get-current-user()` you must use `wp_get_current_user()`.

Comment: oh thanks @jack

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `WP_DEBUG*` constants in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
// prevents debugging messages from appearing in the browser
```

...then you should be able to use [`error_log()`](https://php.net/error_log) in your code, and your debugging messages will be saved in `wp-content/debug.log`. (You'll probably have to ensure that `wp-content/debug.log` exists and is writable by the server to make this work.)

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515556/1094518

Comment: Hi Pat, am not writing an error log. its a custom log for the different events i mentioned above

Comment: The function's name is `error_log()`; you can write out any messages you like, error or not, using it.